# Placing the apple full screen meta tags in a Meteor app

Tags: html, ipad, mobile-safari, meteor

I am attempting to give the illusion of a native iPad app using the Meteor.js 
I am unsure where to place these tags

```
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
```

So far, I have deployed it in several different places without success.
I am brand new to using meteor and would appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You place these tags in your `index.html` file between `<head>` i.e

```
<head>
    <title>test app</title>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
</head>

<body>
    {{>greeting}}
</body>

<template name="greeting">
....
```

Comment: Thank you again Akshat. Worked perfectly.

Comment: The meta tag parameters should be separated by commas, not semi-colons.